# cspline in Maxima giving me a result which indicates an error in Maxima

Tags: maxima

I have the following cubic polynomial f(x)=x³  - 3 x² + x -5 for which the cubic spline should provide the exact same polynomial assuming the following data: 
(-1, -10), (0,-5), (1, -6) with second derivative at the extremes f''(-1)=-12, f''(1)=0 (note that f''(x)=6x-6.)

Here the piece of code that I tried on:

```
/*  polynomial to interpolate and data */
f(x) := x^3 - 3* x^2 + x - 5$
x0:-1$
x1:0$
x2:1$
y0:f(x0)$
y1:f(x1)$
y2:f(x2)$
p:[[x0,y0],[x1,y1],[x2,y2]]$
fpp(x) := diff(f(x),x,2);
fpp0 : at( fpp(x), [x=x0]);
fpp2 : at( fpp(x), [x=x2]);


/* here I call cspline with d1=fpp0 and dn=fpp2 */
load(interpol)$
cspline(p, d1=fpp0, dn=fpp2);
```

I expected the original polynomial (f(x)=x³ -3 x² + x -5) but I got the result:

(%o40)  (-16*x^3-15*x^2+6*x-5)*charfun2(x,-inf,0)+(8*x^3-15*x^2+6*x-5)*charfun2(x,0,inf)

which does not agrees with the original polynomial.

Evenmore. Here is a test on the results provided by Maxima. 
Code:

```
/* verification */
h11(x)  := -16*x^3 - 15* x^2 + 6* x - 5;
h22(x) := 8* x^3 - 15*x^2 + 6* x - 5;
h11pp(x) := diff(h11(x), x, 2);
h11pp0: at( h11pp(x), [x=x0]);
h22pp(x) := diff(h22(x), x, 2);
h22pp2 : at(h22pp(x), [x=x2]);
```

which throws 66 and 18 as the boundary conditions, which should be instead -12 and 0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you've misinterpreted the arguments `d1` and `dn` for `cspline`. As the description of `cspline` says, `d1` and `dn` specify the first derivative for the spline at the endpoints, not the second derivative.

When I use the first derivative of `f` to specify the values for `d1` and `dn`, I get the expected result:

```
(%i2) f(x) := x^3 - 3* x^2 + x - 5$

(%i3) [x0, x1, x2]: [-1, 0, 1] $

(%i4) [y0, y1, y2]: map (f, %);
(%o4)                   [- 10, - 5, - 6]
(%i5) p: [[x0, y0], [x1, y1], [x2, y2]];
(%o5)           [[- 1, - 10], [0, - 5], [1, - 6]]
(%i6) load (interpol) $

(%i7) cspline (p, d1 = at(diff(f(x), x), x=x0), dn = at(diff(f(x), x), x=x2));
        3      2
(%o7) (x  - 3 x  + x - 5) charfun2(x, minf, 0)
                            3      2
                        + (x  - 3 x  + x - 5) charfun2(x, 0, inf)
```

Comment: Here is from the manual for cspline() : about d1....."if it is unknown the second derivative at x_1 is made to zero (natural cubic spline); if it is equal to a number, then the second derivative is calculated based on this number ".  what does it mean by: "the second derivative is calculated based on this number?" . I believe that the manual is a bit confusing here.

Comment: I agree the description is ambiguous. I think what it means is that if `d1` is specified, then that specific number is the first derivative, and the second derivative is some value which is derived from that.